# How to match only the digits that are between two dots excluding the dots using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have series of numbers (versioning) like this:

> `1.6.8`
>   `1.9.7` (also with two digits in the middle)

How should I do to target only the middle numbers, the ones between dot and dot?

I tried something like that this:

```
\.\d+(?=\.)
```

and it is targeting the middle number, but also the first dot.

Comment: Then try `(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)`. Or use a capturing group, `\.(\d+)\.`

Comment: Wiktor's second suggestion is much more readable than the first one, and should work fine. A simpler solution might be to use split(".")

Comment: The first approach it's not working for me and I already tried the second one, but it's also selecting the dots and not just the numbers

Comment: Well, I posted my comment when the question had no `javascript` tag. Certainly, the first regex won't work in the majority of current JS environments. The second one does exactly what you need once you access Group 1 value. And since you tried it before all you need to know is how to get to the groups which is a long solved issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var myRegexp = /\d+\.(\d+)\.\d+/;

var match = myRegexp.exec('1.33.4');
console.log(match[1]); //33
var match = myRegexp.exec('441.54.12345647');
console.log(match[1]); //54
match = myRegexp.exec('13.2222.33');
console.log(match[1]); //2222

match = myRegexp.exec('version 1.2.3');
console.log(match[1]); //2

function getMiddle(inputversion) {
    var myRegexp = /\d+\.(\d+)\.\d+/;
    var match = myRegexp.exec(inputversion);
    if(match != null) {
        if(match.length > 0) {
            return match[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

console.log('should be 34:', getMiddle('my app version: 1.34.55'));
console.log('should be null:', getMiddle('my app needs no versions.it.is.awesome'));
```

The group selector () matches the most  middle digits.
The + makes sure also larger numbers than 9 can get captured.

https://regex101.com/r/wFgpRI/3

Comment: Hmm, that is targeting all the numbers and not just the ones between the dots.
That's why I tried \.\d+\. but that it's also returning the dots and not just the numbers

Comment: @pitygacio added example on how to extract the group.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need for using regex here. You could use `split`:

```js
var versions = '1.6.8 1.9.7'

console.log(versions.split(' ').map(el => el.split('.')[1]))
```

If you don't want to use that method, you could use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559290/how-to-match-only-the-digits-that-are-between-two-dots-excluding-the-dots-using/56559463#comment99698604_56559290) anyway, as pointed out by wiktor:

```js
var versions = '1.6.8 1.9.7'
console.log(versions.match(/(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)/g))
```

Comment: When running the second snippet, I get an error: "*Unexpected quantifier (l14, c30)*"

Comment: Then it might be a browser issue (MS Edge here)

Comment: This is because some browsers do not support the positive look-behind feature in regex (`?<=regex`)